# Unable to create disk from snapshot using google cloud engine API

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to create a disk from a snapshot using google cloud python API:

```
def createDisk(compute, project, zone):
  config = {
    'name': disk_name
  }

  return compute.disks().insert(
    project=project,
    zone=zone,
    sourceSnapshot='global/snapshots/' + snap_name,
    body=config).execute()
```

But it throws:

```
TypeError: Got an unexpected keyword argument "sourceSnapshot"
```

According to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/disks/insert) it should be possible:

> Creates a persistent disk in the specified project using the data in the request. You can create a disk with a sourceImage, a sourceSnapshot, or create an empty 500 GB data disk by omitting all properties. You can also create a disk that is larger than the default size by specifying the sizeGb property.

I need it to automate an image creation which I want to base on the 'dummy' instance. The image should then be used to create a disk which in turn will be used in the instance template for the auto scaling.

Any tips on that one? Is it possible? If no, the `sourceSnapshot` reference be in the docs is really misleading?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Despite what the text says, the Parameters box only shows `sourceImage`.

Comment: Maybe you use the `sourceImage` parameter for both, and it figures out whether it's an image or a snapshot automatically.

Comment: @Barmar: I tried also, but: `"Invalid value for field 'resource.sourceImage': ''. Must be a URL to a valid image resource."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It came out that `sourceSnapshot` should be part of the body request, not an argument. So that would work:

```
def createDisk(compute, project, zone):
  config = {
    'name': disk_name,
    'sourceSnapshot': 'global/snapshots/' + snap_name,
  }

  return compute.disks().insert(
    project=project,
    zone=zone,
    body=config).execute()
```